# alert dialog box isn't displaying on a click

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

In this program when you will clicl on the textview the alertdialog should pop-up. but noting is happening when I am clicking on the textview..
I am sharing the code. please help me with the same.

```
mforgotpasswordlink.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            final EditText resetMail;
            resetMail = new EditText(view.getContext());
            AlertDialog.Builder passwordReset;
            passwordReset = new AlertDialog.Builder(view.getContext());
            passwordReset.setTitle("Reset Password?");
            passwordReset.setMessage("Enter Your Email to Recieve Reset Link");
            passwordReset.setView(resetMail).setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    String mail;
                    mail = resetMail.getText().toString();
                    mFirebaseAuth.sendPasswordResetEmail(mail).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                            Toast.makeText(loginActivity.this, "Reset Link Send To Your Email.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception i) {
                            Toast.makeText(loginActivity.this, "Error! Reset Link is not Send.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });

                }
            }).setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                }
            });

        }
    });
```

logcat part:

```
Build Date                       : 06/07/18
OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: EV031.22.00.01_06
Local Branch           `enter code here`          : 
Remote Branch                    : refs/tags/AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.UM.6.5.R1.08.01.00.312.086
Remote Branch                    : NONE
Reconstruct Branch               : NOTHING
2020-08-19 20:35:40.085 8295-8361/com.example.login D/vndksupport: Loading /vendor/lib/hw/gralloc.msm8953.so from current namespace instead of sphal namespace.
2020-08-19 20:35:40.091 8295-8361/com.example.login I/Adreno: PFP: 0x005ff087, ME: 0x005ff063
2020-08-19 20:35:40.097 8295-8361/com.example.login I/zygote: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasWideColorDisplay retrieved: 0
2020-08-19 20:35:40.098 8295-8361/com.example.login I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
2020-08-19 20:35:40.099 8295-8361/com.example.login D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 2
2020-08-19 20:35:40.129 8295-8361/com.example.login D/vndksupport: Loading /vendor/lib/hw/android.hardware.graphics.mapper@2.0-impl.so from current namespace instead of sphal namespace.
2020-08-19 20:35:40.130 8295-8361/com.example.login D/vndksupport: Loading /vendor/lib/hw/gralloc.msm8953.so from current namespace instead of sphal namespace.
2020-08-19 20:35:40.144 8295-8347/com.example.login D/FA: Connected to remote service
2020-08-19 20:35:41.622 8295-8301/com.example.login I/zygote: Do full code cache collection, code=126KB, data=75KB
2020-08-19 20:35:41.623 8295-8301/com.example.login I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=124KB, data=61KB
2020-08-19 20:35:41.649 8295-8295/com.example.login I/AssistStructure: Flattened final assist data: 2912 bytes, containing 1 windows, 10 views
2020-08-19 20:35:41.656 8295-8361/com.example.login D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllActiveAnimators on 0x91bd2b00 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0x91597720
2020-08-19 20:35:44.080 8295-8301/com.example.login I/zygote: Do partial code cache collection, code=124KB, data=67KB
2020-08-19 20:35:44.082 8295-8301/com.example.login I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=124KB, data=67KB
2020-08-19 20:35:44.082 8295-8301/com.example.login I/zygote: Increasing code cache capacity to 512KB
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add one line at the end of onClick block

```
public void onClick(View view) {
        final EditText resetMail;
        resetMail = new EditText(view.getContext());
        AlertDialog.Builder passwordReset;
        passwordReset = new AlertDialog.Builder(view.getContext());
        .
        .
        .

       passwordReset.create().show(); //add this line

    }
```

Comment: actually I am facing onemore issue.after clicking on the login button I'm going to the next page but at that moment only it is showing that your app stopped.and this is happening every time....can you help me with the same..there is no error comming in logcat..

Answer (score 0):

You have created the Alert Dialog but forgot to show or create it.

You have to return the `create()` method on the `AlertDialog` object in order to show the alert box.

I've updated your code and added the `create()` function after the `setNegativeButton` :

```
mforgotpasswordlink.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            final EditText resetMail;
            resetMail = new EditText(view.getContext());
            AlertDialog.Builder passwordReset;
            passwordReset = new AlertDialog.Builder(view.getContext());
            passwordReset.setTitle("Reset Password?");
            passwordReset.setMessage("Enter Your Email to Recieve Reset Link");
            passwordReset.setView(resetMail).setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    String mail;
                    mail = resetMail.getText().toString();
                    mFirebaseAuth.sendPasswordResetEmail(mail).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                            Toast.makeText(loginActivity.this, "Reset Link Send To Your Email.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception i) {
                            Toast.makeText(loginActivity.this, "Error! Reset Link is not Send.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });

                }
            }).setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                }
            });
            return passwordReset.create();
        }
    });
```

I hope this works for you.

Comment: actually I am facing onemore issue.after clicking on the login button I'm going to the next page but at that moment only it is showing that your app stopped.and this is happening every time....can you help me with the same..there is no error comming in logcat..

Comment: Can you share the ss of logcat?

Comment: 2020-08-22 01:20:33.051 2650-2678/? I/VoiceInputManagerWrapper: VoiceInputManagerWrapper.shutdownVoiceInternal():95 shutdownVoiceInternal()

Comment: W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.example.login/.loginActivity
2020-08-22 01:20:21.947 2039-2082/? I/ActivityManager: Showing crash dialog for package com.example.login u0
2020-08-22 01:20:21.960 2039-2081/? W/BroadcastQueue: Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.DROPBOX_ENTRY_ADDED flg=0x10 (has extras) } to com.google.android.gms/.stats.service.DropBoxEntryAddedReceiver

Comment: 2020-08-22 01:20:21.961 2039-2081/? W/BroadcastQueue: Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.DROPBOX_ENTRY_ADDED flg=0x10 (has extras) } to com.google.android.gms/.chimera.GmsIntentOperationService$PersistentTrustedReceiver
2020-08-22 01:20:21.995 2039-12438/? I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4

Comment: this is comming in logcat

Comment: @robin It will be great if you ask another question for this problem because I am not able to understand it here.

Comment: follow this link please... https://stackoverflow.com/q/63507737/14132368

Comment: @robin I checked the question but it's way too off topic. I would recommend to draft a question in a way that it is specific to the particular problem you are facing, instead of trying to get all your issues resolved in one question try focusing on only one problem per question. Only that way the community would help you solve it. So, please reform the question and update it.

Comment: actually its just a single problem...that is having issue while storing data in firebase

Comment: Okay, but you've to frame the question in a way that it looks like its not off-topic. Like the title you've given is wrong way to write titles. You should have written few words that describes your problem like "App crashing on going to login activity". And then don't provide all the code and logs, just add the relevant section of the code and logs. If then someone asks for more detail then edit it.

Comment: Forget about crashing on goining to login activity..actually I have added a new part that is sotring data on firebade on my register activity. In that I'm facing an error and Have share the code of that only..This is a major issuse I'm facing. Please help me with the same

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63601430/data-is-not-getting-stored-on-firebase-cloud-firestore-using-android-studio

Comment: help me....   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63601430/data-is-not-getting-stored-on-firebase-cloud-firestore-using-android-studio